# Rank only the top 10 in a group

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I have the following final select statement:

```
SELECT   ReportingDate
         ,PortfolioID
         ,IssueNme
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC) AS [Rank]
         ,CAST(SUM(Percentage) AS DECIMAL(22,1)) AS [Weight]
FROM     @Worktable as WT
WHERE    WT.IssueType1 IN ('020')
GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, WT.IssueNme
ORDER BY [Weight] DESC
```

However I'd like to see only the top 10 ranked for each portfolioID. How would I do this ensuring that I get the top 10 for each PortfolioID that is grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE`. I would use `RANK` instead, but then you may get more than 10 for each group.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC) AS [RANK]
  ,   ReportingDate
  ,   PortfolioID
  ,   IssueNme
  ,   CAST(SUM(Percentage) AS DECIMAL(22,1))  AS [Weight]
  FROM @Worktable as WT
  WHERE WT.IssueType1 IN ('020')
  GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, WT.IssueNme
)
SELECT 
  ReportingDate
, PortfolioID
, IssueNme
, [Weight]
FROM CTE
WHERE [RANK] <= 10
ORDER BY [Weight] DESC
```

[**Ranking Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the response.  Works perfectly, didn't think about using CTE.